Context menu position wrong after scrolling page
Using several examples found herein, I have a Fiddle that allows a context-menu for right-clicking on the two right-most columns of a table
It seems to work fine. (I right clicked on Row 6)

But when the table is larger than the original window, things seem to go awry.  Scrolling the window so that the previously unseen portion of the table is now visible puts the context menu in the wrong position. (I right-clicked on Row 8)

Not sure, but I'm guessing something about top and left are determined based on visible portions of the table and so the calculation is off, but I don't know how to properly compensate.

Post your [mcve] here, in a snippet, not on jsFiddle please

You need to use clientX and clientY instead of pageX and pageY in your contextmenu event handler.
Edited to include a working snippet, based on @Eddie's Fiddle; Per @Ryan's suggestion.


function openContextMenu(x,y) {
    $("#myContextMenu").css('visibility' , 'visible' ) ;
    $("#myContextMenu").css({left:x, top:y});
    $("#myContextMenu").css('opacity' , 1 ) ;
    /*$("#myContextMenu").css('left' , x + 'px' ) ;
    $("#myContextMenu").css('top' , y + 'px' ) ;*/

}

onload = function() {

  $("[event-type='individual']").on('contextmenu', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault() ;
    openContextMenu( e.clientX, e.clientY ) ;
  })

  document.addEventListener('click',function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
       $("#myContextMenu").css('visibility','hidden')
    }, 101)
  })
  

}
#mytable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#mytable td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#myContextMenu {
    border: 1px solid black;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: red;
  
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(143, 144, 145, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(143, 144, 145, 1);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(143, 144, 145, 1);    

}

#content-container {
    position: relative;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='content-container'>

<table id='mytable'>
<tr>
<td athlete=34567 event=1 event-type='relay'>1</td>
<td athlete=34567 event=2 event-type='individual'>2:42.96</td>
<td athlete=34567 event=3 event-type='individual'>25.30</td>
</tr><tr>
<td athlete=12345 event=1 event-type='relay'>2</td>
<td athlete=12345 event=2 event-type='individual'>2:12.96</td>
<td athlete=12345 event=3 event-type='individual'>23.30</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td athlete=23456 event=1 event-type='relay'>3</td>
<td athlete=23456 event=2 event-type='individual'>2:02.60</td>
<td athlete=23456 event=3 event-type='individual'>21.31</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td athlete=34567 event=1 event-type='relay'>4</td>
<td athlete=34567 event=2 event-type='individual'>2:42.96</td>
<td athlete=34567 event=3 event-type='individual'>25.30</td>
</tr><tr>
<td athlete=12345 event=1 event-type='relay'>5</td>
<td athlete=12345 event=2 event-type='individual'>2:12.96</td>
<td athlete=12345 event=3 event-type='individual'>23.30</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td athlete=23456 event=1 event-type='relay'>6</td>
<td athlete=23456 event=2 event-type='individual'>2:02.60</td>
<td athlete=23456 event=3 event-type='individual'>21.31</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td athlete=34567 event=1 event-type='relay'>7</td>
<td athlete=34567 event=2 event-type='individual'>2:42.96</td>
<td athlete=34567 event=3 event-type='individual'>25.30</td>
</tr><tr>
<td athlete=12345 event=1 event-type='relay'>8</td>
<td athlete=12345 event=2 event-type='individual'>2:12.96</td>
<td athlete=12345 event=3 event-type='individual'>23.30</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td athlete=23456 event=1 event-type='relay'>9</td>
<td athlete=23456 event=2 event-type='individual'>2:02.60</td>
<td athlete=23456 event=3 event-type='individual'>21.31</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td athlete=34567 event=1 event-type='relay'>10</td>
<td athlete=34567 event=2 event-type='individual'>2:42.96</td>
<td athlete=34567 event=3 event-type='individual'>25.30</td>
</tr><tr>
<td athlete=12345 event=1 event-type='relay'>11</td>
<td athlete=12345 event=2 event-type='individual'>2:12.96</td>
<td athlete=12345 event=3 event-type='individual'>23.30</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td athlete=23456 event=1 event-type='relay'>12</td>
<td athlete=23456 event=2 event-type='individual'>2:02.60</td>
<td athlete=23456 event=3 event-type='individual'>21.31</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td athlete=34567 event=1 event-type='relay'>13</td>
<td athlete=34567 event=2 event-type='individual'>2:42.96</td>
<td athlete=34567 event=3 event-type='individual'>25.30</td>
</tr><tr>
<td athlete=12345 event=1 event-type='relay'>14</td>
<td athlete=12345 event=2 event-type='individual'>2:12.96</td>
<td athlete=12345 event=3 event-type='individual'>23.30</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td athlete=23456 event=1 event-type='relay'>15</td>
<td athlete=23456 event=2 event-type='individual'>2:02.60</td>
<td athlete=23456 event=3 event-type='individual'>21.31</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td athlete=34567 event=1 event-type='relay'>16</td>
<td athlete=34567 event=2 event-type='individual'>2:42.96</td>
<td athlete=34567 event=3 event-type='individual'>25.30</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div id="myContextMenu">
This is my context menu.  There are many like it, but this one is mine.
</div>
</div>




+1 You should update the fiddle and provide a link to show it working. If you've never done it before, open the OPs fiddle, make changes, click save, copy the new URL.
